ActiveX will be disabled by default in Microsoft Office 2024
Microsoft announced in September 2024:
Starting in new Office 2024, the default configuration setting for ActiveX objects will change from Prompt me before enabling all controls with minimal restrictions to Disable all controls without notification. This change applies to the Win32 desktop versions of Word, Excel, PowerPoint, and Visio.
This means we have to replace all ActiveX Buttons, Dropdowns etc. which is a big problem at such short notice.
Question: Will this affect also Win64 desktop versions of Word, Excel, PowerPoint, and Visio?

This only applies to Office 2024 initially, and you can change it via registry/group policy if need be. 365 won't be affected until April 2025.

The term "Win32" was introduced with 32-bit Windows, to distinguish from the previous 16-bit version. However, the terms "Win32" and "Win32 API" are now typically used synonymously with "Windows API", regardless of the application or operating system's bitness (32-bit or 64-bit). (Microsoft source here.)
As you note in the question, the Microsoft announcement to which you refer states (my bold text):

Starting in new Office 2024, the default configuration setting for ActiveX objects will change from Prompt me before enabling all controls with minimal restrictions to Disable all controls without notification. This change applies to the Win32 desktop versions of Word, Excel, PowerPoint, and Visio.

In this context, I am sure that this means all desktop versions of those Office applications will be affected, whether 32-bit or 64-bit.
